# How to remove the ASCII code 28 0x1C (FS) from a Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, character, ascii

I have the following code snippet

```
@trunkarray = split(/:/,$trunkid);
my $compString = "";

foreach $value ( @trunkarray ) {
    print "<TR> <TD> $value </TD> </TR>";

    if ( ! ($compString) ) {
        $compString = "$value";
    }
    else {
        $compString = $compString . ",$value";
    }
}   

&updateOperation($compString);
```

The `$CompString` variable is sent to `updateOperation`.

My script is giving a special character `FS` (code point 28 or 0x1C) after the comma `,` along with `$value` in the above statement. I found this special character's occurrence when I pasted the output in Notepad++.

Can anyone please tell me the reason why I'm getting this special character, and if there is a way to remove it?

Due to this special character, my database operation (under the updateOperation subroutine) is getting aborted; As this string is passed as an argument for an update operation like this:

```
sub updateOperation
{
    my($trunkgrplist) = @_;
    $UPDATE= "update TRUNKGROUP set source='D' where trunkgrpid in ($trunkgrplist)";
..
}
```

Comment: Presumably the character `FS` (`"\x1C"`) is already present in the `$trunkid` variable. What is the source of that value?

Comment: Please add the following `use Data::Dumper;` `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` `print Dumper \@trunkarray;` and show the results

Comment: The source for trunkid is from the form, the checkboxes being checked is the result for the trunkid, separated by a ':' (colon).

Comment: I has selected the following three numbers:
428331  
428332  
428333  

And after using your above sent code "use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \@trunkarray;"

I got the following output for the print :

$VAR1 = [ 428331, "\034428332", "\034428333" ];

Comment: ALso, I just found out that this special character I'm receiving while querying the database itself.

Could you please tell me how to remove this special character while splitting the queried output?

Comment: The simple answer is `tr/\x1C//d`, but that is a hack to work around a separate bug in your code. You should fix the bug rather than remove its effects. If the value of `$trunkid` is the contents of a single database column then it may well be a problem with the code that writes to the database, but you should show the SQL statement that retrieves is for us to be sure

Comment: @Borodin: I think the simple answer would be to add it in the split regex `split(/:\0?/,$trunkid)`. But you are right, there is a bug lingering somewhere else.

Comment: @SruthiNalin: [You really should use `$dbh->prepare`](https://xkcd.com/327/)!! It's probably unsafe if you don't.

Comment: I am adding a module into the existing code. I may not be able to change the existing code for the way it generates the database output when queried.
But thanks @Borodin, I was able to execute my update query now with the transliteration operator you mentioned.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S., what would dbh -> prepare do?

Comment: You would write your query with `?` at the place you want your variables and then put the variables in the `execute`. like this:  `my  $UPDATE = "update TRUNKGROUP set source='D' where trunkgrpid in (?)"; … my $sth = $dbh->prepare($UPDATE); $sth->execute($trunkgrplist);` This circumvents all the fallacies you could fall into if you want to escape the data yourself. Here is the documentation for `DBI`: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#prepare.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S.: That would be `split /:\x1C?/, $trunkid`

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, you have the equivalent of

```
my $compString = "428331:\x{1C}428332:\x{1C}428333";
```

You can fix it with

```
$compString =~ s/\x1C//g;
```

or

```
$compString =~ tr/\x1C//d;
```

Your code becomes

```
sub updateOperation {                                  # XXX Bad name
   my @trunk_grp_ids = @_;

   while (@trunk_grp_ids) {
      my $trunk_grp_ids_list =
         join ', ',
            map $dbh->quote($_),
               splice(@trunk_grp_ids, 0, 500);

      $dbh->do("
         UPDATE TRUNKGROUP
            SET source='D'
          WHERE trunkgrpid in ( $trunk_grp_ids_list )
      ");
   }
}   

my $compString = "428331:\x{1C}428332:\x{1C}428333";   # XXX Bad name
$compString =~ tr/\x1C//d;
my @trunk_grp_ids = split /:/, $compString;
updateOperation(@trunk_grp_ids);
```

Comment: woops! I wrote `FC` everywhere instead of `1C`. Fixed.